# Error: Call to undefined function get_meta() in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I have inherited a custom wordpress theme and am doing a few changes to it (all cosmetics of changing city names, etc) , but at the bottom of a post I get the error : "Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_meta()"

In my functions.php I have this:

```
function bardetails(){
    $web = get_meta('web');
    $email = get_meta('email');
    //...
}
```

I have a Java background but am new to php and wordpress. I dont see anywhere else this function is called, but must be tied to a post.

Have looked and can find a lot of problems about "get_post_meta()" and "meta()" but nothing about this. It also seems to be working on the other site the theme is on. I used FTP to pull over everything and all the other parts of the site seem to work fine. Looked at the database for something that could help with no luck, and also have tried to find if this is some kind of library, as the intention of the function is clear and thats to grab the website/email of the post.

So is this just a straight custom function? And if so were should it be defined in a php/wordpress setup?

Comment: get_post_meta() https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: In the codebase where it was working, have you tried searching for `get_meta`?

Comment: `get_meta()` is not a core WordPress function

Comment: @randommman Yeah thats what my research led me to, as you can see though its not "get_post_meta" but "get_meta"

Comment: @Progrock Yeah, its used in the exact same places due to me pulling that code to start with. I'm thinking maybe it was deprecated? I see other functions that are very close to what this is, but close doesn't cut it in the coding world. Also I checked and the site that its currently working on is running the same version of Wordpress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to a plugin that was not installed. "More Fields" By Henrik Melin, Kal Ström is a seemingly defunct plugin that was needed that allows you to use "get_meta()".  For now, I just copied over the plugin but seems like I need to find an alternative going forward.